# efficiently getting all documents in an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all results from a match-all query in an elasticsearch cluster.  I don't care if the results are up to date and I don't care about the order, I just want to steadily keep going through all results and then start again at the beginning.  Is scroll and scan best for this, it seems like a bit of a hit taking a snapshot that I don't need.  I'll be looking at processing 10s millions of documents.

Comment: Scroll and Scan does look like a fit here. What are you trying to do with the scans? Aggregations, Updates, or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [elasticsearch query to return all records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records)

Comment: Bit of a duplicate, but the overhead concern is somewhat unique. I'll take a stab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat of a duplicate of [elasticsearch query to return all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records). But we can add a bit more detail to address the overhead concern. (Viz., "it seems like a bit of a hit taking a snapshot that I don't need.")

A [scroll-scan search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) is definitely what you want in this case. The 
"snapshot" is not a lot of overhead here. The documentation describes it metaphorically as "*like* a snapshot in time" (emphasis added). The actual implementation details are a bit more subtle, and quite clever.

A slightly more detailed explanation comes later in the documentation:

> Normally, the background merge process optimizes the index by merging together smaller segments to create new bigger segments, at which time the smaller segments are deleted. This process continues during scrolling, but an open search context prevents the old segments from being deleted while they are still in use. This is how Elasticsearch is able to return the results of the initial search request, regardless of subsequent changes to documents.

So the reason the context is cheap to preserve is because of how Lucene index segments behave. A Lucene index is partitioned into multiple segments, each of which is like a stand-alone mini index. As documents are added (and updated), Lucene simply appends a new segment to the index. Segments are write-once: after they are created, they are never again updated.

Over time, as segments accumulate, Lucene will periodically do some housekeeping in the background. It scans through the segments and merges segments to flush the deleted and outdated information, eventually consolidating into a smaller set of fresher and more up-to-date segments. As newer merged segments replace older segments, Lucene will then go and remove any segments that are no longer actively used by the index at large.

This segmented index design is one reason why Lucene is much more performant and resilient than a simple B-tree. Continuously appending segments is cheaper in the long run than the accumulated IO of updating files directly on disk. Plus the write-once design has other useful properties.

The snapshot-like behavior used here by Elasticsearch is to maintain a reference to all of the segments active at the time the scrolling search begins. So the overhead is minimal: some references to a handful of files. Plus, perhaps, the size of those files on disk, as the index is updated over time.

This *may* be a costly amount of overhead, *if* disk space is a serious concern on the server. It's conceivable that an index being updated rapidly enough while a scrolling search context is active may as much as double the disk size required for an index. Toward that end, it's helpful to ensure that you have enough capacity such that an index may grow to 2–3 times its expected size.

Comment: Great answer, disk space is not a huge concern as although we will be having a considerable number of writes, we will have fixed ttls so it should be more or less constant at least.